# Regular Expression in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to replace all tags which are like `<xxxx>`.

I tried this:

```
- (NSString *)grabData:(NSString *)searchTerm {
// Setup an error to catch stuff in 
NSError *error = NULL;
//Create the regular expression to match against
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<.*>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
// create the new string by replacing the matching of the regex pattern with the template pattern(whitespace)
NSString *newSearchString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:searchTerm options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchTerm length]) withTemplate:@""];   
NSLog(@"New string: %@",newSearchString);
return newSearchString;
}
```

But this just doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is `regex` nil? If so, what is the error?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post all the code where you attempt to replace the regex matches in a string.

Comment: Let me guess: You have multiple tags in the string and almost the whole string is removed?

Comment: What was the test input string, what did you get after the replacement, and what did you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is. [input (click)](http://pastie.org/3092003), output is " ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `<.*>` matches a less-than, any amount of anything *including a greater than*, and then a greater-than. This pattern would, for instance, match a complete HTML file...

What you need is a `<[^>]+>` the `[^>]` is the set of all characters excluding greater-than, the `+` is "one or more", so the whole thing matches a less-than, one or more of anything *excluding* a greater than, and then a greater-than.

Comment: You can test your regular expressions online here: http://regexpal.com/
CRD was correct here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is incorrect.

1. < and > are meta characters and need escaping
2. The pattern matching should be .+

Based on this use

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\<.+\\>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

and it should work

Comment: Xcode tells me "Unknown escape sequence '\>' and the output string is " ".

Comment: Yes it needs double escape backslashese to escape characters. Should be OK now.

Comment: Xcode Warning is okay now, but the output string is still " ".